# JavaFX CSS effect help (screenshots)

Tags: java, css, effects, javafx-2

I can't figure out how can I apply this kind of effect to the text-field in javaFX 2 using css (-fx-... :...);

[image]

I need something like in the screenshot. I have an panel with that background and i need for the text field to darken it up a little (it looks like an inner shadow).

I tried using smaller opacity on the panel and high opacity on the text input but is not working properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this sample app:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StyleDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField txt = new TextField("text");
        txt.setLayoutY(150);
        txt.setPrefHeight(50);
        txt.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.11); -fx-text-fill: white; -fx-font-size: 28; -fx-font-weight: bold");

        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThghN.png\"); -fx-background-repeat: stretch; -fx-background-size: 300 250;");
        root.getChildren().add(txt);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

To give an inner shadow effect to the text field, check this link out:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeeffect